# React Error while selecting the material UI select list item

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

> **Uncaught Error: React DOM tree root should always have a node reference.**
>   *In the invariant.js:42 file*

I have searched a lot but could not find any proper solution. Could you kindly help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Could you provide some code as where the error occurs